# Issues with a navbar, how to make it non-fixed?

Tags: html, css

This is an example I have an issue with:

So when I scroll, navbar is going as well because of fixed property and ruins the look, how to make it go away with logo on a scroll?

Also can someone suggest me if this is a good for a beggining and if there are some more things which I should take care of. I want to make right side for random widgets and left side for a content.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Test Design
</head>
<style>
 /* Body style */
 body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  
 }
 
 /* Logo */
 .header {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  background: #fff !important;
  padding: 8px 16px;  
 }
 .logo-1 {
    font-family: Helvetica, "serif";
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 37px;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
 font-weight: 900;
    color: #555555;
    display: block;
 }
 
 /* Navigation */
 .navbar {
  Position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  background: #333333;
     list-style-type: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;

 }
 
 li {
  float: left;
 }
 
  li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  color: #eee;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "sans-serif";
 }
 
  li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background: #111111;
 }
 
  .active {
  background-color: #008cba;
 }
 
 /* Widget */
 .widget {
  position:relative;
  bottom: -42px;
  float: right;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 190px;
  border-left: 1px solid #9fa2a9;
  display: block;
  padding: 2px 5px;
 }
 
 </style>
<body>
 <div class="header"><a class="logo-1" href="#">Test Design</a></div>
<!-- Navigation -->
<ul class="navbar">
 <li><a class="active" href="#">Home</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
 <li style="float: right"><a class="active" href="#">Register</a></li>
 <li style="float: right"><a href="#">Login</a></li>
 </ul>
<!-- Widget -->
<div class="widget">

 <b><u>Random bullshit lorem-ispum</u></b>
 <form action="#" method="post">
    <div>
         <label for="name">Text Input:</label>
         <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" tabindex="1" />
    </div>

    <div>
         <h4>Radio Button Choice</h4>

         <label for="radio-choice-1">Choice 1</label>
         <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-1" id="radio-choice-1" tabindex="2" value="choice-1" />

     <label for="radio-choice-2">Choice 2</label>
         <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-2" id="radio-choice-2" tabindex="3" value="choice-2" />
    </div>

  <div>
    <label for="select-choice">Select Dropdown Choice:</label>
    <select name="select-choice" id="select-choice">
      <option value="Choice 1">Choice 1</option>
      <option value="Choice 2">Choice 2</option>
      <option value="Choice 3">Choice 3</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div>
    <label for="textarea">Textarea:</label>
    <textarea cols="40" rows="8" name="textarea" id="textarea"></textarea>
  </div>

  <div>
      <label for="checkbox">Checkbox:</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox" />
    </div>

  <div>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </div>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.navbar {
    position: relative;
    background: #333333;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Change navbar position -

Comment: Hello, changing position to relative makes navbar white (non-existent)

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS

Issue Here is , you are making the `li` elements float left, so its parent `ul` height gets collpased, to retain its height you need a clearfix.

CSS

```
body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-size: 12px;

    }

    /* Logo */
    .header {
        position: relative;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        display: block;
        height: 50px;
        background: #fff !important;
        padding: 8px 16px;      
    }
    .logo-1 {
    font-family: Helvetica, "serif";
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 37px;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    font-weight: 900;
    color: #555555;
    display: block;
    }

    /* Navigation */
    .navbar {
        width: 100%;
        background: #333333;
        list-style-type: none;
        text-decoration: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        text-align: center;

    }

  .clearfix::after{
    content:"";
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    clear:both;
  }

    li {
        float: left;
    }

     li a {
        display: block;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        color: #eee;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-align: center;
    background-color: #212121;
        font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "sans-serif";
    }

     li a:hover:not(.active) {
        background: #111111;
    }

     .active {
        background-color: #008cba;
    }

    /* Widget */
    .widget {
        position:relative;
        bottom: -42px;
        float: right;
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 190px;
        border-left: 1px solid #9fa2a9;
        display: block;
        padding: 2px 5px;
    }
```

[Link for reference](https://jsfiddle.net/DChandraShekhar/fzvjupok/1/)
Hope this Helps..

Comment: @Shadow ... COOL :D.. Happy Coding

Answer (score 0):

/* Navigation */

```
.navbar {
        Position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        background: #333333;
        list-style-type: none;
        text-decoration: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        text-align: center;

    }
```